# Where are the DNS Zone files located?

Tags: dns

I am using `Centos 7` and I would like to modify zone records in `php` so that I can add and remove domain names programatically.

Unfortunately, when I type `find / named.conf` into a terminal I get 0 results and I do not have the folder `/var/named`.

How can I find the files I need to modify so that I am able to write a script to add and removed domains names?

After running `mydomain.com` as @Leo suggested, I received:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 mydomain.com -t NS

; <<>> DiG 9.13.4 <<>> @8.8.8.8 mydomain.com -t NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33602
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.      IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns2.contabo.net.
mydomain.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns1.contabo.net.
mydomain.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns3.contabo.net.

;; Query time: 55 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 25 02:35:26 GMT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

Comment: Let's back up a second. Is your computer running a DNS server?

Comment: @duskwuff no but I have VPS hosting for a CMS I am developing. The DNS records must exist somewhere because I can manually edit them, add domains etc. manually by logging into my hosting account. I'm just trying to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are the DNS Zone files located?

Somewhere internal to your hosting provider. You aren't operating the DNS server, so its zone files won't be on your server.

Your provider may offer an API to update your DNS records. If they do, use it. (I can't say for sure if they do, because you haven't mentioned who they are.)

If that isn't an option, there are plenty of third-party DNS providers available who do have an API. A couple of the bigger ones to consider are [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/) (free), [AWS Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) (~$0.50/zone/month), and [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/) (~$0.20/zone/month).

Comment: I am with Contabo. This is the only information I can find https://blog.contabo.com/inside/dns-feature-contabo-customer-control-panel/ There is no mention about an API that I can use.

Comment: Yikes. Yeah, never mind. Consider moving your site (or at least your DNS hosting) to a different provider.

Comment: I don't really want to change hosting providers. What about if I installed and configured `BIND`? Also, I would quite like to setup my own custom nameservers, which may help solve the problem. Unfortunately, the tutorial explains how to do it with `cPanel` or `Plesk`. https://blog.contabo.com/tag/nameserver/ I am not using a web panel.

Comment: As someone who runs their own DNS server: don't do that to yourself. If you want your own DNS, consider using Cloudflare, AWS Route 53, or Google Cloud DNS.

Comment: I tried using Cloudflare. It worked well for a few hours, then I received `Error 523 Origin is unreachable` and I was also unable to access my website via `SSH`. I was thinking of writing a `Curl` script to add and remove domains but it seems like there might be security issues.

Comment: @DanBray I didn't mean passing traffic through Cloudflare, just using them as a DNS provider. They have an official API, although I'm not sure if you can add domains as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

To get a hint of where to start searching, look at reality; try:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 your.host.name -t NS
```

or `drill`, or `kdig` or etc.

Comment: I typed in the `dig` command and pasted the results into my question.

Answer (score -1):

`dig @ns1.contabo.net. version.bind CH TXT` tells that ns1 (which speculative truly might be the primary) is using PowerDNS.
The most common use (of many other options) of PowerDNS is i.c.w. MySQL.
So my best guess is that your ISP offers an web interface, to their database that holds the zone data.

To answer your question "Where are the DNS Zone files located?":
the zone data resides in several rows of a database table.
It's unlikely (but not impossible) that there are static zones-files.
And if so, I highly doubt that they would collect them from your filesystem.

For real answers better ask support at your supplier.